# Stopping Gmail from sending base64 attachments

Tags: gmail, attachment

There is an email I need to send but attachments can't be base64 or my email gets rejected.
I checked within Gmail settings to see if there was some sort of option to change that but found nothing.

Is there any way to make the Gmail web client send "normal" attachments?

Comment: base64 *is* "normal"

Answer (score 3):

> Gmail (Web GUI)
>
> Does not work for sending patches.
>
> Gmail web client converts tabs to spaces automatically.
>
> At the same time it wraps lines every 78 chars with CRLF style line breaks although tab2space problem can be solved with external editor.
>
> Another problem is that Gmail will base64-encode any message that has a non-ASCII character. That includes things like European names.

[Source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/process/email-clients.html#gmail-web-gui).